# Efficiently putting integer after decimal point in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I have any unsigned `long` value. All I want to do is put it after a double's dot (in decimal representation), like this:

> myLong = 1024
>   dotLong = 0.1024

I could do it based on the amount of digits I've scanned, while writting a scanner.

```
private long scanDecDigits()
{
    int digIndex = 0;
    char ch;

    while (input.remains())
    {
        ch = input.get();

        if (!AS3Char.isDecDigit(ch))
            break;

        // Push up to 10 digits; ignore rest.
        if (i < 10)
            numDigits[digIndex++] = ch - '0';
    }

    decBase = Math.pow(10, digIndex);

    long sub = decBase;
    long value = 0;

    for (digIndex = 0; sub != 0; sub /= 10)
        value += numDigits[digIndex++] * sub;

    return value;
}
```

Alternatively, this works too:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(putInDecimal(255));
    }

    public static double putInDecimal(long lv)
    {
        return ((double) lv) / ((double) tenPow(lv));
    }

    public static long tenPow(long lv)
    {
        return (lv < 10)  ? 10 :
               (lv < 100) ? 100 :
               (lv < 1e3) ? (long) 1e3 :
               (lv < 1e4) ? (long) 1e4 :
               (lv < 1e5) ? (long) 1e5 :
               (lv < 1e6) ? (long) 1e6 :
               (lv < 1e7) ? (long) 1e7 :
               (lv < 1e8) ? (long) 1e8 :
                            (long) 1e9;
    }
}
```

Tips.

Comment: You can use `Math.log10` and `Math.pow` in `tenPow` instead of the ternary operators.

Comment: Does your first code block even compile? Where are `input`, `v`, `decBase`, etc. defined?

Comment: Simpler solution (probably less efficient though): `Double.parseDouble("0." + lv)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest and clearest solution is (as already said):

```
return Double.parseDouble("0."+lv);
```

More mathematical solution:

```
return lv / Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(lv + 1)));
```

Both only work for non-negative values. If you need to manage negative numbers, this should work:

```
return lv / Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(lv) + 1)));
```

Comment: _Both only work for positive values;_, so it means this doesn't work for `0`? Let me see...

Comment: Sorry, I should have written for "non-negative" values. Editing my post to reflect that